# Generate dynamic check boxes values from the servlet response

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, servlets

I have values coming from database in a servlet response as id and name; and I am storing it in a `Map` `key-value` in a servlet.

I wanted to now create a `JSP` code which generates a checkboxes and show the dynamic list of values.

**Servlet code**

```
String sql = "SELECT customerid , c_name from customer";
ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery(sql);
Map<String, String> options = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

while (rs.next()) {
options.put(rs.getString("customerid"), rs.getString("c_name");
}

String json = new Gson().toJson(options);
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.getWriter().write(json);
```

**JSP Code**--

```
$(document).ready(function () {                           
    $('.btn-checkbox').click(function () {      
    $.get('dataservlet', function (responseJson) {
    var $input = $('#id1');
    var $type = 'checkbox';
        $.each(responseJson, function (key, value) {              
        $('$type').val(key).text(value).appendTo($input); 
    });
    });
});

//JQuery is not generating the right checkboxes, even when the response is in, need help in forming the correct JQuery.
```

**HTML Code**--

```
div id="id1"></div>
```

*example*-

I have a record coming as-

```
customerid c_name
5000       name1
```

and I needed a checkbox to get generated as:

```
<input type ="checkbox" id'5000"/>name1
```

// so here `key` is *id* and `value` is *name1*

I needed a check-box with values in it as below image-

[image]

**UPDATE**

[image]

Comment: $('#vehicleChkBox').change(function(){
     cb = $(this);
     cb.val(cb.prop('checked'));
 });

Comment: Thanks Pawan, can you please provide the whole JQuery example, it would be better to understand it that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it totally wrong. Use the following lines. **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s6LR7/)**

```
var append = $('<input type="'+$type+'">'+value+'</input>').attr('id',key).val(value);

$($input).append('<br/>').append(append);
```

- `$type` cannot be used as string - `$('$type')`
- key is your ID - so you cannot use it using `.val()`.
- Why are you appending it to the input, you should insert the new checkboxes after input - **[.after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/)**.
- And your forget to end `$(document).ready()` with `});`.
- Use `.change()` and not `.click()` incase of inputs.

So your final JS :

```
$(document).ready(function () {                           
    $('.btn-checkbox').change(function () {      
        $.get('dataservlet', function (responseJson) {
            var $input = $('#id1');
            var $type = 'checkbox';
            $.each(responseJson, function (key, value) {              
               var append = $('<input type="'+$type+'">'+value+'</input>').attr('id',key).val(value);
               $($input).append('<br/>').append(append); 
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks shaunakde, I have updated my question in terms of HTML code, basically I have a `div` with id as `id1` where I need to populate all the check boxes with the values, and I have tried your code and I am getting all the checkboxes but no values? :( is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Please check the updated image that I am getting after the changes you mentioned..